# How to update pom version and dependency version using maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have multiple Java maven projects that are hosted as Services

One project is common jar that is added  as dependency in other services

Now, I need to update version in pom after each build and same version needs to be updated in other services. I am using Jenkins as build tool

I checked for snapshot but it seems to be deprecated. Please help with alternative

Comment: `<dependencyManagement>` in one pom can host shared dependency versions. If not feasible, you might need to change the hierarchy of the projects.

Answer (score 2):

To automatically update the version in the dependent projects, you can use the Maven Versions plugin. This plugin provides goals to update the version of the project and its dependencies.

Here are the steps to update the version of the common jar project and propagate the same version to other dependent projects:

Add the Maven Versions plugin to your common jar project's pom.xml file:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

In the Jenkins build job for the common jar project, use the following Maven command to update the project version:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=<new_version>
```

Replace <new_version> with the new version you want to set.

After the common jar project is built and its version is updated, you can use the following Maven command to update the version of the common jar dependency in your other services:

```
mvn versions:update-parent
```

This command will update the parent version of the dependent projects to match the new version of the common jar project.

Finally, you can build the dependent projects with the updated version of the common jar dependency.

By using the Maven Versions plugin and the above steps, you can automate the process of updating the version of the common jar project and its dependencies in your Jenkins build job.

Comment: I would suggest to use the most recent version of the versions-maven-plugin https://github.com/mojohaus/versions/releases/tag/2.15.0